# Keyboard layout related issue - fixed in GUI but receive error in terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, keyboard

I run on Ubuntu 14.04. I have an issue related to the keyboard layout in GUI mode. I managed to fix it in the GUI by using:
`setxkbmap -layout us` [1]
and adding it to the `~/.bashrc`. That works fine. However, the problem I have now is that when I login to the text-mode terminal I receive an error - `Cannot display "default display"`. This is not surprising because this command does not work in text mode.

The question is: where should I put [1] and have no error in text mode terminal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue is solved. Added script to `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ "$TERM" = "xterm" ]; then 
setxkbmap -layout "us"
fi
```